# messaging an existing sql query to include a count column

Tags: sql-server

I have a large SQL query that returns a classic asp ADO.Recordset.  I want to add a column to the query that simply contains a count of all the distinct PublicationID's along with all the other data, how to?  Below is just a sample as I don't want to paste the query due to it's size etc.  I know I want to use COUNT(DISTINCT na.publicationid) but I am not sure how to shoehorn it into an existing query, return the existing data but with an additional column.

```
SELECT na.publicationid, na.nameabbrev
FROM NewspaperAd as na
WHERE na.publicationid = '12345'
```

I want to add something like:

```
SELECT na.publicationid, na.nameabbrev, COUNT(DISTINCT na.publicationid) as distnct_p_id
FROM NewspaperAd as na
WHERE na.publicationid = '12345'
```

Comment: Actually, your query doesn't have anything to do with ADO. It returns a resultset, which ADO turns into an ADO Recordset.

Comment: can you run multiple sql statements?

Comment: Mitch, it would add a lot of traffic to the database which I was trying to avoid by doing it in one query.  @John, true, slightly pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, your "count" query makes no sense. You want to see "12345", plus the "nameabbrev" column for NewspaperAd 12345, and you want to see the number of publications? over all rows? That's two separate queries.

Comment: No it doesn't make sense which is why I asked the question.  I was just trying to explain what I was trying to do, if I could get the syntax right and knew how to do it I wouldn't have asked!

Comment: @flavour: that's not what I mean. I mean your query is asking two independent questions, and should really be two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Seperate the Query:

```
SELECT na.publicationid, na.nameabbrev
,(Select COUNT(publicationid) 
FROM NewspaperAd 
WHERE publicationid = na.publicationid) as distnct_p_id
FROM NewspaperAd as na
WHERE na.publicationid = '12345'
group by na.publicationid, na.nameabbrev
```